# Particular solution to differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}$=$\frac{3}{2y}$ and y=4 when x=5

I started with 2y dy = dx

I don't think I started off right.

My teachers solution:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\int 2y \ dy=\int 3\ dx$$
Integrate each side
gives $$y^2=3x+K$$
So when $y=4$, $x=5$
gives $K=1$
So$$y^2=3x+1$$

Comment: Thanks for this it was easier for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your method is also fine. But you are skipping 3 on right hand side.

Comment: Its actually  my teachers solution but I didn't really understand it

Comment: this is a comment and not an answer!